# Limit Per Criteria

Tags: sql, mysql, optimization, greatest-n-per-group

I have an articles table and a categories table. I want to fetch 7 articles for each category. Currently I have this but it's terrible slow on large tables so it's not really a solution:

```
SELECT id, 
       title, 
       categories_id, 
       body, 
       DATE_FORMAT(pubdate, "%d/%m/%y %H:%i") as pubdate   
FROM articles AS t 
WHERE ( 
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM articles 
    WHERE t.categories_id = categories_id 
      AND id< t.id AND publish = 1 
      AND expires > '2008-12-14 18:38:02' 
      AND pubdate <= '2008-12-14 18:38:02' 
    ) < 7 
ORDER BY categories_id DESC
```

Using explain, it shows me it's doing a join type ALL & REF. The select types are PRIMARY and DEPENDENT SUBQUERY .

Is there a better solution?

Comment: This appears to get all the articles for categories for which there are fewer than 7.  Which seems to be slightly different than your English description of your goal.  For example, if a category had ten articles, your description made it sound like you'd want 7 of them, not 0.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I'd solve this problem:

```
SELECT a1.id, 
       a1.title, 
       a1.categories_id, 
       a1.body, 
       DATE_FORMAT(a1.pubdate, "%d/%m/%y %H:%i") as pubdate  
FROM articles AS a1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN articles AS a2
  ON (a1.categories_id = a2.categories_id AND 
     (a1.pubdate < a2.pubdate OR (a1.pubdate = a2.pubdate AND a1.id < a2.id)))
GROUP BY a1.id
HAVING COUNT(*) < 7;
```

A correlated subquery usually performs poorly, so this technique uses a join instead.

For a given article, search for articles (a2) that match the category of the current article under consideration (a1), and have a more recent date (or higher `id` in the case of a tie).  If there are fewer than seven articles that meet that criteria, then the current one must be among the most recent of its category.

If you can rely on the unique `id` column having the same sort order as `pubdate`, then you can simplify the join because there will be no ties over a unique column:

```
  ON (a1.categories_id = a2.categories_id AND a1.id < a2.id)
```

Comment: Good suggestion, that looks like the right way to do it, should work in all cases and should be fast.

Answer (score 2):

1. How big are the tables, and how slow is slow?
2. What indexes are there on the tables?
3. What is the entire information from EXPLAIN?

Also, the two datetime values are explicit, so it looks like this is either being generated from code generated by something composing it from other information. Is there another SQL query of some kind, which is executing this within a loop on a list?

It's not clear which 7 articles are being chosen - the most recent? By which date?

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like you're asking for those categories with fewer than 7 articles; so that's where the query should start --

```
SELECT categories_id,  COUNT(1)  
FROM articles  
WHERE publish = 1 
  AND expires > '2008-12-14 18:38:02' 
  AND pubdate <= '2008-12-14 18:38:02'
GROUP BY categories_id
HAVING COUNT(1) < 7
```

Then make that a subquery with:

```
SELECT 
    c.id, c.title, c.id, a.body,  
    DATEFORMAT(a.pubdate, "%d/%m/%y %H:%i") as pubdate  
FROM categories c  
JOIN articles a ON c.id = a.categories_id  
JOIN 
(  
    SELECT DISTINCT categories_id  
    FROM articles  
    WHERE publish = 1  
        AND expires > '2008-12-14 18:38:02'  
        AND pubdate <= '2008-12-14 18:38:02'  
    GROUP BY categories_id  
    HAVING COUNT(1) <= 7  
) AS j ON c.id = j.categories_id  
ORDER BY whatever
```

The next step is to limit the number of articles returned to 7 - I can deal with that next if this looks proper. (Try it as-is and see what EXPLAIN looks like.)

EDIT: Changed "< 7" to <= 7"

Answer (score 0):

You have several options - some might result in performance issues but it depends on many factors.

You could split it into several queries. One query to read out all the categories:

```
SELECT categories_id FROM Categories
```

Then for each category, read out the top seven articles:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  title, 
  ...etc.
FROM articles
where categories_id = 1
```

... and so on for each category.

This has the benefit of being a bit simpler to understand but the downside is it turns one query into 1 + (1* number of cats). Then again, you could put a limit on the number of categories so you have some element of control. Sometimes you find that 5 simple queries perform a lot better than 1 complicated one!

This kind of assumes you are calling the SQL from some code you have control of - is this the case?

Comment: I've never seen the case where decomposing a sql statement with a subquery into a loop with just the subquery has improved performance, unless there was some fixable fault in the first.

Answer (score 0):

In testing I found that the Limit 7 doesn't work within subqueries in MySQL, please see Bill's suggestion which I verified that it works well.

```
SELECT id, 
       title, 
       categories_id, 
       body, 
       DATE_FORMAT(pubdate, "%d/%m/%y %H:%i") as pubdate   
FROM articles A INNER JOIN articles B ON B.categories_ID = A.Categories_ID
WHERE A.ID IN ( 
    SELECT ID
    FROM Articles  
    WHERE categories_id = A.categories_id 
      AND publish = 1 
      AND expires > '2008-12-14 18:38:02' 
      AND pubdate <= '2008-12-14 18:38:02' 
    LIMIT 7
    ORDER BY Categories_ID DESC) 
ORDER BY B.Categories_ID DESC
```

Comment: Only since the most recent versions has MySQL supported subqueries; and optimization isn't very good on them. So this is testable, but needs to be compared with other types of approaches.

Comment: Putting the LIMIT 7 into the subquery isn't going to limit the number of rows - it just limits the number of records in the subquery to match on. Better to SELECT DISTINCT in the subquery - then it will just look at one row per category, not 7

Comment: Good point, originally it was ambiguous whether he wanted the top 7 rows in each category or the catetories with less than 7, and has lately clarified it as the the latest 7 articles of each catetory.

Comment: I defer to the wisdom of Bill on this one whose suggested method is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Although Bill's query might work a bit better on average, on a single run it took 230 secs. I didn't do a full test (several runs) but it's still too slow so i guess the better option would be to do 1 query per category fetching the latest 7 items - that looks like it's going to be faster than all other options.

Comment: Do you have indexes set up for the columns in the WHERE criteria?